# On submitting the form, trying to create custom card component in different page, Unable to export the after Onclick

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './NewAccountPage.css'
import FormInput from "./formInput";
import Cards from "../../Cards/Card";

function NewAccountPage() {
  const initialValues = { firstName: "", lastName: "" ,email: "", password: "", mobileNumber: "" };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };

  const none = 0;

  const createCardComponent =() => {
    return (<div>
      <Cards name={"pending"} />
      karthik
      </div>)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formErrors);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      console.log(formValues);
    }
  },
    [formErrors]);
    
  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;
    const reg = /^[0-9]*$/i;
    const alphaNumeric = /^[A-Za-z]+$/i;

    if (!values.firstName) {
      errors.firstName = "First Name is required!";
    } else if (!alphaNumeric.test(values.firstName)) {
      errors.firstName = 'First Name should only contains Alphabets from A-Z or a-z';
    }

    if (!values.lastName) {
      errors.lastName = "Last Name is required!";
    }  else if (!alphaNumeric.test(values.lastName)) {
      errors.lastName = 'Last Name should only contains Alphabets from A-Z or a-z';
    }

    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Email is required!";
    } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "This is not a valid email format!";
    }

    if (!values.mobileNumber) {
      errors.mobileNumber = "Mobile number is required!"
    } else if (!reg.test(values.mobileNumber)) {
      errors.mobileNumber = "This is not a valid Mobile number format"
    }

    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit ? (
        <div className="ui message success">Account Created Successfully</div>

      ) : (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(formValues, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      )}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>New Account Form</h1>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
        <div className="ui form">
          <FormInput
            label={"First Name"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"firstName"}
            placeholder={"First name"}
            value={formValues.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.firstName}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Last Name"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"lastName"}
            placeholder={"Last name"}
            value={formValues.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.lastName}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Email"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"email"}
            placeholder={"Email"}
            value={formValues.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.email}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Mobile Number"}
            name={"mobileNumber"}
            placeholder={"Mobile Number"}
            value={formValues.mobileNumber}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.mobileNumber}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="field">
          <div className="NewAccountPage__drop">
            <select className="ui fluid search dropdown ">
              <option value="">Account Type</option>
              <option value="1">Savings</option>
              <option value="2">Netbank Saver</option>
              <option value="3">Current</option>
              <option value="4">Cheque</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button onClick={createCardComponent} className="fluid ui button blue ">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export { createCardComponent} 
export default NewAccountPage;
```

I am trying to call a function on click of the submit button, That function
createCardComponent() needs to trigger a card component and render dynamically on different javascript files. Tried different things, but did not work. Unable to export the function createCardComponent to a different page. Let me know how to fix the errors

Comment: `createCardComponent` is a part of `NewAccountPage` component. You won't be able to export and use it the way you intend to. I'd suggest lifting it up to the parent component and pass it on as prop to the `NewAccountPage`

Answer (score 0):

Create useState to maintain the click,
if clicked, render the component

You cannot export the component from here, maintain a prop in context and in different file export the component

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './NewAccountPage.css'
import FormInput from "./formInput";
import Cards from "../../Cards/Card";

function NewAccountPage() {
  const initialValues = { firstName: "", lastName: "" ,email: "", password: "", mobileNumber: "" };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };

  const none = 0;

  const createCardComponent =() => {
    return (<div>
      <Cards name={"pending"} />
      karthik
      </div>)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formErrors);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      console.log(formValues);
    }
  },
    [formErrors]);
    
  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;
    const reg = /^[0-9]*$/i;
    const alphaNumeric = /^[A-Za-z]+$/i;

    if (!values.firstName) {
      errors.firstName = "First Name is required!";
    } else if (!alphaNumeric.test(values.firstName)) {
      errors.firstName = 'First Name should only contains Alphabets from A-Z or a-z';
    }

    if (!values.lastName) {
      errors.lastName = "Last Name is required!";
    }  else if (!alphaNumeric.test(values.lastName)) {
      errors.lastName = 'Last Name should only contains Alphabets from A-Z or a-z';
    }

    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Email is required!";
    } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "This is not a valid email format!";
    }

    if (!values.mobileNumber) {
      errors.mobileNumber = "Mobile number is required!"
    } else if (!reg.test(values.mobileNumber)) {
      errors.mobileNumber = "This is not a valid Mobile number format"
    }

    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit ? (
        <div className="ui message success">Account Created Successfully</div>

      ) : (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(formValues, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      )}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>New Account Form</h1>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
        <div className="ui form">
          <FormInput
            label={"First Name"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"firstName"}
            placeholder={"First name"}
            value={formValues.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.firstName}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Last Name"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"lastName"}
            placeholder={"Last name"}
            value={formValues.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.lastName}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Email"}
            type={"text"}
            name={"email"}
            placeholder={"Email"}
            value={formValues.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.email}</p>

          <FormInput
            label={"Mobile Number"}
            name={"mobileNumber"}
            placeholder={"Mobile Number"}
            value={formValues.mobileNumber}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <p className="NewAccountPage__p">{formErrors.mobileNumber}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="field">
          <div className="NewAccountPage__drop">
            <select className="ui fluid search dropdown ">
              <option value="">Account Type</option>
              <option value="1">Savings</option>
              <option value="2">Netbank Saver</option>
              <option value="3">Current</option>
              <option value="4">Cheque</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button onClick={(e) => setClicked(true)} className="fluid ui button blue ">
          Submit
        </button>
      {clicked ? createCardComponent() : null }
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export { createCardComponent} 
export default NewAccountPage;
```